# What is the specified format of abstracting data from the database to laravel charts

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I have been trying to get a bar chart of all the users based on when they have been registered but I keep getting this error

> "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: DATE_FORMAT (SQL:
>   select * from "users" where (DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y')) = 2019)"

I am using sqlite and here is my controller

```
use App\Charts\AnimalChart;

  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y'))"),date('Y'))
            ->get();
        $chart = AnimalChart::database($users, 'bar', 'highcharts')
            ->title("Monthly new Register Users")
            ->elementLabel("Total Users")
            ->dimensions(1000, 500)
            ->responsive(false)
            ->groupByMonth(date('Y'), true);
        $user = User::paginate(5);

        return view('admin.index', compact('user', 'chart'));
    }
```

My view

```
<h1> Graphs</h1>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Chart Demo</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    {!! $chart->html() !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{!! Charts::scripts() !!}
{!! $chart->script() !!}
<div>
```

Any help will be welcomed

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT()` is a `MySQL` (and maybe others) function; there is no such function in `SQLite`. Are you looking for https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html?

Comment: So I guess datetime is the equevalent format

Comment: Likely so. I don't know SQLite very well, but something to be aware of is that Laravel is designed to be DB agnostic; the functions are meant to work with all DBs. If you use Eloquent functions, like `->whereYear()` instead of `->where(DB::raw(...))`, you won't get this issue.

Comment: I am definitely using that. But in the stade of creating the chart I am facing this error "Call to undefined method App\Charts\AnimalChart::database()"

Comment: That's a separate issue; I don't know what an `AnimalChart` is, or how to use it. If using `->whereYear()` handles the current issue, either close this question by adding a self-answer and open a new question related to you new issue, or edit this question to reference the new issue only.